# Angular MODx multilingual template

Tags: angularjs, internationalization, multilingual, modx

I've got a Website running on MODx CMS with angularjs app on one of the pages. The site is multilingual and all translations ar stored in MODx Lexicons (physical in php files). So I want the thranslations of angular apps to be stored in MODx too, to make it easier for the user.

Sure, I can load needed translated terms from MODx via some request, store them in scope and use in angular view. But I don't wont to list all the needed terms manually.

Can I do something like: I use in my template for example {{translation.price}}, {{translation.land}}, {{translation.submit}} etc. If some of theese are not defined in scope, then the request will be sent? How can I bult this "reverse" logic between template and the app? **If var in template is not defined, call the function.**

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how you are setup, but if you place your javascripts into Modx chunks, then modx will process them & you can then use Modx tags in your javascript.

Comment: hm... but I have all the content I need to translate in angular views as separate html files... not sure I can place them in chunks...